# How to run a test that a full page reload didn't take place using Cucumber, Marionette

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, marionette

I am working on a task where links which had done a full refresh will now instead load their content via a marionette view.

I want to write a test which verifies that I have made this change.

I could test that user lands on the correct page by looking at the content, but is there a way to run the test so that it verifies there was not a complete page reload? Possibly a test which confirms that a specific javascript method was called??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Selenium driver (possibly others, I don't know...) you can use `page.driver.browser.execute_script` to execute JS directly on the page.  You could potentially execute some JS that would set a value on a global var, then call the link, then check that the var is still holding the same value.

Setting the value:

```
page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{
  window.testPageVar = "still here!";
}
```

Reading the value:

```
returnVal = page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{
  return window.testPageVar;
}
```